# How to get table row data in array format wth help of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new in JavaScript. I want  when I click on edit button that's specific row data fetch out and I want to get the table row data in array with the help of jquery.

```js
$('.role-edit-btn').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();

  var formid = $(this).attr("formid");
  var data = $(formid).serialize();
  json_data = JSON.stringify(data);
  alert(json_data);
});
```

```html
<form id="RoleNae">
  <tr class="table">
    <td>
      <?php echo $Sr; ?> </td>
    <td class="text-capitalize RoleName">
      <?php echo $value['RoleName']; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col">
          <a class="btn btn-block">
              <i class="fas fa-solid fa-trash btn-delete" style="color:red;" RecordId="<?php echo $value['RoleId']; ?>" TableName="role" PrimaryKey="RoleId" FunctionCallingUrl="controller/RoleController.php" FunctionCalling="DeleteRole" RedirectPage="ViewRole.php" ></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</form>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your jquery references `.role-edit-btn`, but this is not present in your provided HTML, so does nothing.

Comment: It *looks like* you have a `form` in the middle of a `table` - as in `table > tbody > form > tr` - this is not valid HTML and the browser will *automatically* change this.